# Where x * (p - 1) / p come from?

Tags: education, programming

I was doing a programming exercice, it took me a lot of time, and when I finished and checked the result, I saw that a lot of people used a formula that I could not understand to solve it where as I used a more algorithmic approach.

Here is the exercise:

> If you consider a given number d, how many proper fractions can be built using d as a denominator?
>
> For example, let's assume that d is 15: you can build a total of 8 different proper fractions between 0 and 1 with it: 1/15, 2/15, 4/15, 7/15, 8/15, 11/15, 13/15 and 14/15.
>
> You have to build a function that computes how many proper fractions you can build with a given denominator

The mathematical approach that most people answered is like this:
Given a number (N), the first step is to calculate the prime factors (PF) of N. Then, they reduce the PF by using this formula:

$$ result = 1$$

for each element $pf_i$ in PF

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n i = result = result * (1 - \frac{1}{pf_i}) $$

with:

$pf_i$ a prime factor,

$n$ the number of prime factors

Then the answer of the question is $result * N $. Where does this formula come from ?

Comment: $a/d$ is proper iff $0 < a < d$ and $a$ and $d$ are coprime. How many numbers less than $d$ are coprime with $d$? Easier question to answer: How many numbers less than $d$ are *not* coprime with $d$?

Comment: [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: @Michael Lee For each $pf_i$ the product from i = 1 to N

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi  Thanks !